# apc_fetch() returns FALSE despite the key is known in APC-Cache

Tags: php, caching, symfony, apc

I got a little and strange problem with the APC. In our code we have to deserialize some hundred big arrays from json and this operation is really expensive. Now I tried to deserialize and store the array in APC, but apc_fetch() returns false on next request.

```
$items = $entity->getItems();  // JSON-String

$cacheKey = __FUNCTION__ . '_itemcache_' . $entity->getId() . '_' . md5($items);
$cacheItems = apc_fetch($cacheKey);

if(false === $cacheItems) {
    $cacheItems = json_decode($items, true);
    apc_store($cacheKey, $cacheItems, 3600);
}

// ...
```

I can see all cached items in apc.php and I can also fetch them from other applications with the same server-config. What could be wrong? This snippet is taken from a symfony-project, but how far I can see there isn't any other apc-code in use.

Any ideas? I already searched here and on google, but I didn't found any helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should check params like:

```
apc.max_file_size = 512M
```

and few others. Also be aware that APC isn't made to handle a single large variabile. For big data your best bet is to use a Database.

Comment: I get the serialized data from the database...

APC has all cache items and I can fetch it from everywhere expect the writing application.